# Why is this Binary Tree return true instead of false?

Tags: go, binary-tree, race-condition

My goal is to use Binary Tree for Operation Room Booking. The problem is the `return false, nil` magically become `return true, nil`. I am not sure if this is a race condition or not. But I am confused.

The error print (full)

```
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestInsert$ github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/cipta_integrasi_nusantara_backend/bookingkamaroperasi -count=1

=== RUN   TestInsert
2023/01/13 12:34:18 new          2022-01-01 10:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 12:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 SafeDB_v2.Insert true
2023/01/13 12:34:18
2023/01/13 12:34:18 node         2
2023/01/13 12:34:18 diff         3h0m0s false
2023/01/13 12:34:18 existing     2022-01-01 10:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 12:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 new          2022-01-01 15:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 17:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BinaryTree.insert ok true <nil>
2023/01/13 12:34:18 SafeDB_v2.Insert true
2023/01/13 12:34:18
2023/01/13 12:34:18 node         2
2023/01/13 12:34:18 diff         6h0m0s false
2023/01/13 12:34:18 existing     2022-01-01 10:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 12:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 new          2022-01-01 18:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 20:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 node         2
2023/01/13 12:34:18 diff         1h0m0s true
2023/01/13 12:34:18 existing     2022-01-01 15:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 17:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 new          2022-01-01 18:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 20:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BookingKamarOperasi_v2.isLessThanTwoHoursApart return 2, nil
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BinaryNode.ok 2 false
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BinaryTree.insert ok true <nil>
2023/01/13 12:34:18 SafeDB_v2.Insert true
2023/01/13 12:34:18
    /Volumes/T7Touch/Work/technical_test/cipta_integrasi_nusantara_backend/bookingkamaroperasi/db_v2_test.go:31: 01-01-2022 18:00-20:00 = true; want false; error <nil>
--- FAIL: TestInsert (0.00s)
FAIL
FAIL    github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/cipta_integrasi_nusantara_backend/bookingkamaroperasi      0.422s
```

The error print (focus)

```
2023/01/13 12:34:18 node         2
2023/01/13 12:34:18 diff         6h0m0s false
2023/01/13 12:34:18 existing     2022-01-01 10:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 12:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 new          2022-01-01 18:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 20:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 node         2
2023/01/13 12:34:18 diff         1h0m0s true
2023/01/13 12:34:18 existing     2022-01-01 15:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 17:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 new          2022-01-01 18:00:00 +0700 WIB 2022-01-01 20:00:00 +0700 WIB
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BookingKamarOperasi_v2.isLessThanTwoHoursApart return 2, nil
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BinaryNode.ok 2 false
2023/01/13 12:34:18 BinaryTree.insert ok true <nil>
2023/01/13 12:34:18 SafeDB_v2.Insert true
```

The code specific to the error print

```
            log.Println("BinaryNode.ok " + strconv.Itoa(isLess) + " " + strconv.FormatBool(false)) // line 126: BinaryNode.ok 2 false
            return false, nil // line 127
```

So, my expectation, `BinaryTree.insert` should return `false, nil`. Instead, it return `true, nil`

The code specific to the error print

```
        ok, err := t.root.insert(data) // line 58: BinaryTree.insert ok true <nil>
        log.Println("BinaryTree.insert ok", ok, err) // line 59
```

The code

```
package bookingkamaroperasi

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type BookingKamarOperasi_v2 struct {
    startDate time.Time
    endDate   time.Time
}

// Return
// 0 = the startDate overlaps with an existing booking
// 1 = left
// 2 = right
func (n *BookingKamarOperasi_v2) leftOrRight(data BookingKamarOperasi_v2) (int, error) {
    if data.endDate.Before(n.startDate) {
        log.Println(data.endDate, n.startDate)
        // scenario 1: endDate n.startDate
        return 1, nil
    } else {
        // scenario 2: n.startDate endDate

        if data.startDate.Before(n.endDate) {
            // scenario 3: n.startDate startDate n.endDate
            return 0, errors.New("startDate overlaps with an existing booking")
        }

        return 2, nil
    }
}

type BinaryNode struct {
    left  *BinaryNode
    right *BinaryNode

    data BookingKamarOperasi_v2
}

type BinaryTree struct {
    root *BinaryNode
}

func (t *BinaryTree) insert(startDate, endDate time.Time) (bool, error) {
    data := BookingKamarOperasi_v2{startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}

    if t.root == nil {
        t.root = &BinaryNode{
            left: nil, right: nil,
            data: data}
        log.Println("new", "\t", t.root.data.startDate, t.root.data.endDate)
        return true, nil
    } else {
        ok, err := t.root.insert(data)
        log.Println("BinaryTree.insert ok", ok, err)
        return ok, err
    }
}

// Return
// 0 = this method is not to be used directly
// 1 = false
// 2 = true
func (n *BookingKamarOperasi_v2) isLessThanTwoHoursApart(data BookingKamarOperasi_v2, node int) (int, error) {
    var diff time.Duration
    if node == 1 {
        // endDate n.startDate
        diff = n.startDate.Sub(data.endDate)
    } else if node == 2 {
        // n.startDate n.endDate startDate
        diff = data.startDate.Sub(n.endDate)
    } else {
        return 0, errors.New("this method is not to be used directly")
    }

    log.Println("node", "\t", node)
    log.Println("diff", "\t", diff, diff < 2*time.Hour)
    log.Println("existing", "\t", n.startDate, n.endDate)
    log.Println("new", "\t", data.startDate, data.endDate)

    if diff < 2*time.Hour {
        log.Println("BookingKamarOperasi_v2.isLessThanTwoHoursApart return 2, nil")
        return 2, nil
    } else {
        return 1, nil
    }

}

// This method is not to be used directly.
func (n *BinaryNode) insert(data BookingKamarOperasi_v2) (bool, error) {
    // error.
    if n == nil {
        return false, errors.New("this method is not to be used directly")
    }

    node, err := n.data.leftOrRight(data)
    if node == 0 {
        return false, err
    } else if node == 1 {
        if isLess, err := n.data.isLessThanTwoHoursApart(data, 1); isLess == 0 {
            return false, err
        } else if isLess == 2 {
            return false, nil
        } else if isLess == 1 {
            // continue
        } else {
            return false, errors.New("ok " + strconv.Itoa(isLess) + " is not implemented")
        }

        if n.left == nil {
            n.left = &BinaryNode{left: nil, right: nil, data: data}
        } else {
            n.left.insert(data)
        }

        return true, nil
    } else if node == 2 {
        if isLess, err := n.data.isLessThanTwoHoursApart(data, 2); isLess == 0 {
            return false, err
        } else if isLess == 2 {
            log.Println("BinaryNode.ok " + strconv.Itoa(isLess) + " " + strconv.FormatBool(false))
            return false, nil
        } else if isLess == 1 {
            // continue
        } else {
            return false, errors.New("ok " + strconv.Itoa(isLess) + " is not implemented")
        }

        if n.right == nil {
            n.right = &BinaryNode{left: nil, right: nil, data: data}
        } else {
            n.right.insert(data)
        }

        return true, nil
    } else {
        return false, errors.New("unknown error")
    }
}

type SafeDB_v2 struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    v  BinaryTree
}

func (c *SafeDB_v2) Insert(startDate time.Time, duration time.Duration) (bool, error) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    ok, err := c.v.insert(startDate, startDate.Add(duration))
    log.Println("SafeDB_v2.Insert " + strconv.FormatBool(ok))
    log.Println()
    c.mu.Unlock()

    return ok, err
}

var C_v2 SafeDB_v2

func InitializeDB_v2() {
    C_v2 = SafeDB_v2{v: BinaryTree{}}
}
```

test.go

```
package bookingkamaroperasi_test

import (
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/cipta_integrasi_nusantara_backend/bookingkamaroperasi"
)

func TestInsert(t *testing.T) {
    bookingkamaroperasi.InitializeDB_v2()

    now, err := time.Parse("02-01-2006 15:04Z07:00", "01-01-2022 10:00+07:00")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    // A doctor books on 01/01/2022 10:00 for 2 hours
    if got, err := bookingkamaroperasi.C_v2.TryInsert(now, 2*time.Hour); !got {
        t.Errorf("%v-12:00 = %t; want true; error %v", now.Format("02-01-2006 15:04"), got, err)
    }

    // Another doctor books on 01/01/2022 15:00 for 2 hours
    today15 := now.Add(5 * time.Hour)
    if got, err := bookingkamaroperasi.C_v2.TryInsert(today15, 2*time.Hour); !got {
        t.Errorf("%v-17:00 = %t; want true; error %v", today15.Format("02-01-2006 15:04"), got, err)
    }

    // Another doctor books on 01/01/2022 18:00 for 2 hours
    today18 := now.Add(8 * time.Hour)
    if got, err := bookingkamaroperasi.C_v2.TryInsert(today18, 2*time.Hour); got {
        t.Errorf("%v-20:00 = %t; want false; error %v", today18.Format("02-01-2006 15:04"), got, err)
    }

    // Another doctor books on 01/01/2022 07:00 for 2 hours
    today07 := now.Add(-3 * time.Hour)
    if got, err := bookingkamaroperasi.C_v2.TryInsert(today07, 2*time.Hour); got {
        t.Errorf("%v-09:00 = %t; want false; error %v", today07.Format("02-01-2006 15:04"), got, err)
    }

    // out of scope
    // Another doctor books on 01/01/2022 02:00 for 2 hours
    today02 := now.Add(-8 * time.Hour)
    if got, err := bookingkamaroperasi.C_v2.TryInsert(today02, 2*time.Hour); !got {
        t.Errorf("%v-04:00 = %t; want false; error %v", today02.Format("02-01-2006 15:04"), got, err)
    }
    // Another doctor books on 31/12/2022 23:00 for 2 hours
    yesterday23_today01 := now.Add(-11 * time.Hour)
    if got, err := bookingkamaroperasi.C_v2.TryInsert(yesterday23_today01, 2*time.Hour); got {
        t.Errorf("%v - 01-01-2022 01:00 = %t; want false; error %v", yesterday23_today01.Format("02-01-2006 15:04"), got, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: AH. The problem is on line 139 where I do recursive and I did not handle it properly. Adding `return n.right.insert(data)` does the job.

Comment: Where is your `main` method or what does one need to do to reproduce your problem? And is the code that you posted really the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem? (see [mcve])

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt My bad, here's the test.go file